# Python 2: substitution of chars in a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, loops

I need to convert a string into a new string: Each character in the new string must be '(' if that character appears only once in the original string, or ')' if that character appears more than once in the original string.
Could you please help me?

```
myword = "attachment"

def duplicate_encode(word):
    from collections import Counter
    lst = list(word)
    counts = Counter(lst)
    newwrd = ""
        for key, value in counts.iteritems():
            if value > 1:
                newwrd += key.replace(key, ")")
            else: 
                newwrd += key.replace(key, "(")
        return newwrd

print duplicate_encode(myword)
```

My output: )((((()

Output expected ))))((((()

Edit: in case of upper cases, I do not want to consider them (I.E. "Fanfare" => "))())((" )

Comment: You're not replacing characters in the original string; you're replacing in the keys of your `Counter`. They're not going to end up in the same order.

Comment: Drop `newwrd` entirely and call replace each time on `word`. It's also unnecessary to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved, thanks to Tamas (added word.lower to his solution for the uppercase problem) and thank you all for your help!

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    from collections import Counter
    nwrd = word.lower()
    counter = Counter(nwrd)
    return "".join(")" if counter[c] > 1 else "(" for c in nwrd)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate `Counter` object and replace those characters where count equals `1` by `(` and everything else by `)`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> myword = "attachment"
>>> def duplicate_encode(word):
...     ct = Counter(word)
...     for k, v in ct.items():
...         if v == 1:
...             word = word.replace(k, '(')
...         else:
...             word = word.replace(k, ')')
...     return word
... 
>>> duplicate_encode(myword)
'))))((((()'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `str.join` to map all the characters in a string:

```
from collections import Counter
def duplicate_encode(word):
  counter = Counter(word)
  return "".join(")" if counter[c] > 1 else "(" for c in word)
print duplicate_encode("attachment") # "))))((((()"
```

Comment: Your solution is quite ok but I need to ignore caps while determining if a character is a duplicate.. for example "Success" => ")())())"

Comment: Got it adding a new word.lower() variable